# PHP: Find array difference on values

Tags: php

I have two pretty big arrays with email addresses in them.

`$oldmail` and `$newmail`.

Both looks like this:

```
[0] => some@email.com
[1] => some1@email.com
[2] => some2@email.com
...
```

I want to find all the email values in `$newmail` that does not exist anywhere in `$oldmail`.

I think this should work:

```
foreach ($oldmail as $key => $value) 
{
    foreach ($newmail as $key2 => $value2) 
    {
        if ($value == $value2) 
        {
            //do nothing..
        }
        else
        {
            echo $value2;
        }
    }
}
```

But it is way to resource heavy with big lists.

Is there another more effecient way I can do this?

Comment: I tried array_diff but it does not seam to search through all values - only compares value[0] vs. value2[0] if I understand correct?
It shoud compare value[0] against all values in the other array

Comment: should the comparison be case-insensitive?

Comment: Ahh thats why array_diff() didnt work before, I forgot to strtolower() all the strings :) Thanks!

Comment: @Bolli, accept one of the answers or delete your question if your problem is resolved. Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/760830)

```
<?php
$a1=array("red","green","blue","yellow");
$a2=array("red","green","blue");

$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_diff` in PHP

```
$a1=array("some@email.com","some1@email.com");
$a2=array("some1@email.com","some2@email.com");
$result=array_diff($a2,$a1);
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [1] => some2@email.com )
```

Comment: Why did you copy the other answer?

Comment: thats just the snippet from the official php manual entry for array_diff. They probably both just copied that from there.

Answer (score 1):

**array_diff()** is right choice. It doesn't only matches by index as you mentioned in your comment. It compares all values.

Give this a shot:

```
$result=array_diff($newmail,$oldmail);
print_r($result);
```